# the getText() function in selenium with web element returns null string

Tags: java, html, selenium

so I am learning on [this website](https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/) to learn how to automate using selenium with Java.

my task was to enter **Ind** in the edit box called ***Suggession Class Example*** and then there will be a list that appears like in this image :

[image]

I have to click on **India** and then check if the **editText** had the value **India** as supposed or not.

I manage to do all of that except for one thing that I am facing right now, I can't extract the text in the **editText** back. every time I try to extract it using `.getText()` method, it returns **null string ("")** although the visible text is **India**. I tried many thing like using `.getAttribute("value");` it returned **Ind**, I tried using `.getAttribute("innerText");` it returned **null string ("")**. this is the HTML code of the part I want to extract its text:

```html
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="inputs ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Type to Select Countries" autocomplete="off">
```

as you see there is no attribute that I can use to get the text back.

this is my attempt so far:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/");
        
        WebElement editText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='autocomplete']"));
        editText.sendKeys("Ind");
        
        Thread.sleep(500);
        List<WebElement> suggested = driver.findElements(By.className("ui-menu-item"));
        for(WebElement e : suggested)
            if (e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {
                e.click();
                break;
            }
        Thread.sleep(500);

        System.out.println(editText.getText());
        if(editText.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("India"))
            System.out.println("Success");
        else
            System.out.println("Failed");
        
    }

}
```

and this is the output in the console:

```
Failed
```

everything is done successfully like the clicking part, but my problem is extracting the text back of that **editText**, I don't have any prior knowledge in HTML, thought that someone could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out what is the problem, the problem was in this line :

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

the delay wasn't enough to get the text written back when clicked on the list, so I change it to :

```
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

and it worked.

also I was supposed to use `.getAttribute("value");` instead of `.getText();` to Get the visible text (i.e. hidden by CSS)